# How to format solr result documents?

Tags: xml, solr

I want to format the solr result page instead of just a xml-
show a user only ten results at a time (one page) and provide links for the next or previous page of results.

And add some css .
where and how do i do it?

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the XsltReponseWriter. Which is documented here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter

Here's an example which turns solr's resonse into an atom feed:

https://github.com/mauricio/acts_as_solr/blob/master/jetty/solr/conf/xslt/example_atom.xsl

You could use the header information that solr provides to help with paging.

```
<str name="rows">10</str>
<result name="response" numFound="8104" start="0">
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record (this post is very old). I post here a complete XSLT file that formats Solr results, in a fashion like Google (with page numers, etc).

Your Solr seach, should have the following parameters:
hl=on
hl.fl=content
start=0
rows=10

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output media-type="text/html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- Variables para el paginador -->
<xsl:variable name="pageNumber" select="(response/result/@start div 10) + 1"/>
<xsl:variable name="numberOfRecords" select="response/result/@numFound"/>
<xsl:variable name="recordsPerPage" select="/response/lst[@name='responseHeader']/lst[@name='params']/str[@name='rows']" />
<xsl:variable name="endPage" select="ceiling(response/result/@numFound div 10)" />
<xsl:variable name="cantPages" select="5" />
<xsl:variable name="queryPura" select="/response/lst[@name='responseHeader']/lst[@name='params']/str[@name='q']" />
<xsl:variable name="query" select="substring-after($queryPura, 'OR ')" />

<xsl:key name="preg" match="lst[@name='highlighting']/lst" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<style>
#resultadoBusqueda em {
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
</style>
<table id="resultadoBusqueda">
        <xsl:for-each select="response/result/doc">
        <tr>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                        <div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 16px">
                                <a style="color: #0000cd;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline';" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none';">
                                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="str[@name='url']" /></xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:if test="not(str[@name='title'])"><xsl:value-of select="str[@name='url']" /></xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='title']"/>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-family: arial; color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('preg', ./str[@name='id'])" mode="name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-family: arial; color: #009b00; font-size: 14px;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='url']" />
                        </div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(response/result/doc)">
                <h4>No hay ning&#250;n resultado que concuerde con su b&#250;squeda</h4>
        </xsl:if>

    <!-- Paginador -->
    <xsl:if test="response/result/doc">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="$recordsPerPage &lt; $numberOfRecords">
                    <xsl:if test="$pageNumber &gt; 1">
                        <span style="margin-right: 5px;"><a href="?q={$query}&amp;pag={($pageNumber - 2) * $recordsPerPage}">&lt; Anterior</a> |</span>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="numerosPaginas">
                        <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$pageNumber"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="max">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="(($pageNumber + $cantPages) &gt; $endPage) or ($endPage &lt;= 9)">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$endPage" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="($pageNumber + $cantPages)" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="number">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="(($pageNumber - $cantPages) &lt; 1) or ($endPage &lt;= 9)">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="1" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="($pageNumber - $cantPages)" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:with-param>

                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:if test="(($pageNumber ) * $recordsPerPage) &lt; ($numberOfRecords)">
                            <span style="margin-right: 5px;">| <a href="?q={$query}&amp;pag={($pageNumber) * $recordsPerPage}">Siguiente &gt;</a></span>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <span style="margin-right: 5px;">(Resultados encontrados: <xsl:value-of select="$numberOfRecords" />)</span>
                </xsl:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="arr/str" mode="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- Numeracion de los paginadores -->
<xsl:template name="numerosPaginas">
    <xsl:param name="current"/>
    <xsl:param name="number"/>
    <xsl:param name="max"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$number = $current">
            <!-- Show current page without a link -->
            <span class="current" style="margin-right: 5px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span style="margin-right: 5px;">
                <a href="?q={$query}&amp;pag={($number - 1) * $recordsPerPage}"><xsl:value-of select="$number"/></a>
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <!-- Recursively call the template untill we reach the max number of pages -->
    <xsl:if test="$number &lt; $max">
        <xsl:call-template name="numerosPaginas">
            <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$current"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number+1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$max"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you please guide how to add this file into the project?

Answer (score 0):

Ankit u can add to that xsl file into conf/xslt folder its useful to u.

pls refer that http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter