# How to modify search result page given by Solr?

Tags: java, solr, search-engine, nutch

I intend to make a niche search engine. I am using apache-nutch-1.6 as the crawler and apache-solr-3.6.2 as the searcher. I must say there is very less updated information on web about these technologies.

I followed this tutorial http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial and have successfully installed apache and solr on my ubuntu system. I was also successful in injecting seed url to webdb and perform the crawl.

Using solr interface at `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin`, I can also query the crawled results. But this is the output I receive. [image].

Am I missing something here, the earlier apache-nutch-0.7 had a war which generated a clear html output like this. [image]. How do I achieve this... Or if anyone could point me to a latest tutorial or guidebook, highly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried until now? Did you do any google (if not SO) search? There is a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411330/how-to-format-solr-result-documents

Comment: @Oerd: I did see that question, I posted my query after a good amount of studying and researching. This post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411330/how-to-format-solr-result-documents) definitely suggests using xslt but I wished to know if that is the preferred way.

Comment: xslt *is* the standard way to transform/style xml docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below link 
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2012/06/building-a-java-application-with-apache-nutch-and-solr/
which answered my query.

I agree after reading the content available on above link, I felt very angry at me. 
Solr package provides all the required objects to query solr.

Infact, the essential jars are just solr-solrj-3.4.0.jar, commons-httpclient-3.1.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar.

Anyone can build a java search engine using these objects to query the database and have a fancy UI.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

- If you are just starting, do not use Solr 3.6, go straight to latest 4.1+. A bunch of things have changed and a lot of new features are added.
- You seem to be saying that you will expose Solr + UI directly to general web - that's a really bad idea, as Solr is completely unsecured and allows web-based delete queries. You really want a business layer in a middle.
- With Solr 4.1, there is a pretty Admin UI and, also, there is a /browse page that shows how to use Velocity to do the pages backed by Solr. Or have a look at something like [Project Blacklight](http://projectblacklight.org/) for an example of how to get UI over Solr.

Comment: thanks for replying, should I use apache-nutch-1.6 or should I start with apache-nutch-2.1. Also could you suggest relevant reading material. Awaiting your response.

Comment: I don't know much about nutch. I know version 2 is a complete redesign and still has some features missing as compared with 1.6. On the other hand, if you are just starting, it makes sense to go with the latest one. Good luck.

Comment: Can you suggest same for JAVA.
I mean with Java based WEb Application