# What is the best user interface for solrj search results?

Tags: java, user-interface, solrj

I have used solrj for a JSF web application. I need some guidance for making a nice user interface for search results. I use faceted searching. I have found some projects like Drupal and blacklight and ajax solr but they work with PHP and Ruby on the Rails and JavaScript. What is a good option for java?

Comment: @Sushan Gupta has a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728903/how-to-modify-search-result-page-given-by-solr) on this subject and answered it himself but not specified what kind of UI he used.

Comment: I finally ended up using Ajax-Solr. It seems good but I'm stuck with something that I need to raise another question here for that issue.